# Get single frames byte array from multiframe dicom image using vtk gdcm

Tags: c#, vtk, gdcm

I am reading multiframe dicom as follows and get total pixel data of image in byte array.

```
 gdcm.ImageReader _reader = new gdcm.ImageReader();
_reader.SetFileName("FileName");
_reader.Read(); 
byte[] byteArray= new byte[_reader.GetImage().GetBufferLength()];
_reader.GetImage().GetBuffer(byteArray);
```

but it gives out of memory exception for multiframes having more than 300 frames.
So I want to extract single frames pixel data in a byte array at a time.
Any idea??

Comment: How big is this file? Maybe rather than using a bytearray try using a numpy array -- the memory management maybe be better

array = np.frombuffer(_reader.GetImage().GetBuffer(), dtype = np.uint8)

Are you using 32 or 64 bit Python?

Comment: Its 32 bit. I am not doing it in python, its winforms application.

Comment: Right so it's a win32 .Net application? you'll be limited to 2Gb in RAM - I would suggest moving to 64bit unless you mean the datatype?

Comment: I used gdcm box region and region reader to read single frames byte array. But I have one doubt, please see the answer of this post